# Cycles render artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have 2 surfaces moving away from each other, and when I render on the view panel I have some strange artifacts where the light is more strong (I don't care about it).
But the real issue is when I render to PNG I have a munch of artifacts, like the object is deforming.

I'm new to Blender and to the 3D animation, so if you need any more information just ask it.

Tks for your time.

Render Image Editor
[image]

Render to PNG
[image]

Comment: if you move/rotate the lamp does the effect go away? At first glance it does look like the there is a light source that is just illuminating those areas.

Comment: I could test it. I'm trying to change the samples and the denoise, and I'm getting some improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first image it seems like there is not enough samples and the light areas are really noisy.

In the second image it seems there are blurry spots all over the render, if I understand it correctly, that might be the result of very strong denoising with not enough samples.

My recommendation would be to try increasing the number of samples as well as adjusting the denoising settings for it not to be so strong if needed.

Comment: I made changes on the samples and the denoise, it made some improvements. I have to make some more tests on it.

Comment: After increasing the render samples and reduce the strength of denoising, made a huge difference on the render. Tks for the feedback. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY5my.png